# Is "Billie said he is hungry" a correct alternative to "Billie said I'm hungry"?

Tags: verbs

I understand that said is usually used with reported speech alone, and that told is used with an object. I just want to make sure that the sentence "Billie said he is hungry" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Billie said he is hungry.
2. Billy said I am hungry.

Both the sentences are in indirect speech, but they are different in meaning; they aren't interchangeable.

The former sentence expresses that Billie is hungry, whereas the latter indicates you are hungry.

If you put the sentence #1 in direct speech as follows, both the sentences will convey the same meaning:

Billie said, "I am hungry" (direct speech) = Billie said he is hungry (indirect speech).

As for the use of said and told, both can be used in reported speech.  The "said" is used without an object, whereas the "told" is used with an object as follows:

Billie said he is hungry.

Billie told me he is hungry.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct but it has a different meaning than the other one.

> Billie said he is hungry

means Billie is hungry. On the other hand

> Billie said I'm hungry

means that I am hungry.

You can make it work though.

> Billie said "I'm hungry"
>   Billie said he is hungry

These two may have the same meaning depending on the time in the context. Of course a quotation like this is a bit harder to convey in speech than in text but I can imagine a situation where it can work.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of your question is about punctuation.

- > Billie said he is hungry. (Or better: Billie said he was hungry)

is reported speech and in this sentence "Billie" and "he" represent the same person. It means that Billie is the person who is/was hungry.

- > Billie said I'm hungry.

is reported speech and in this sentence "Billie" and "I" represent two different people. If you are the one uttering the sentence, then "I" stands for you (Azul).

- > Billie said: "I'm hungry".

is direct speech, the quotation marks (" ") indicate that "Billie" and "I" represent the same person.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "Billie said he is hungry" is correct. However, it would also be okay to write either:

- (1) "Billie said I'm hungry"
- (2) "Billie told us he is hungry"

Your sentence is better than the first, because (1) risks confusing the reader (is Billie saying *he* is hungry, or that *the speaker* is hungry?) You could remedy this confusion with punctuation, as Laure mentions. You would also be okay to write (2) since, as you mentioned, it's being used with an object ("us").

Just keep in mind that while any of the three are acceptable, your sentence is the clearest and most natural-sounding, and therefore the best choice.